What is the appropriate way to model an ideal diode with Xschem and ngspice?
I have been trying to model an ideal boost converter using xschem and ngspice, I have defined a custom model for a diode as shown in the second figure below.
The model throws an error that it is incorrect in certain scenarios or just runs the simulator while ignoring the diode model and solving the circuit. (First Screenshot)
This spice model is defined as per the rules and syntax of ngspice, is there a possibility that someone can help me identify what I might be doing wrong here?
Please find the screenshots below:


Thank You for your help!!!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


This spice model is defined as per the rules and syntax of ngspice...

This is not exactly correct.  You are using LTspice syntax for its piecewise-linear (PWL) diode model.  ngspice supports this model type, but you need to set the LTspice compatibility flag before you can use it.  I believe later versions of KiCad automatically set this for you, but older versions of KiCad, other programs which leverage ngspice (e.g. Xschem), and standalone ngspice you need to edit the .spiceinit or spice.rc file as explained here.  The following line should be added to the file:
set ngbehavior=ltpsa

This sets both LTspice (lt) and PSpice (ps) compatibility for the entire netlist (a).  More info for compatibility modes can be found in 12.14.1 of the ngspice manual.  More info on the .spiceinit file can be found in section 12.6 of the same manual.

Another thing to note is that the PWL diode model in ngspice (called "simple diode model" in the documentation) is implemented using the XSPICE extensions.  This doesn't affect Windows users, but for Linux users the XSPICE extensions need to be added to the compile command when installing ngspice.  If you look at section 32.1.2 of the ngspice-42 manual, it says you need to add --enable-xspice to the compilation command.  Starting with ngspice-43, however, XSPICE is enabled by default so you don't need to do anything extra (see section 28.0.1.2 of the ngspice-43 manual).

Hi Kulov, I did try this out during my initial simulation runs and setting it to ltpsa didn't work.

@CobaltBlue  Are you on Windows or Linux?  I suggest trying to run your netlist on native ngspice first to debug it.  Xschem's ngspice integration could have issues finding the required file.

@CobaltBlue Remember, the file name and location needs to be C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\spice.rc for Windows or /home/YOURUSERNAME/.spiceinit for Linux.

yes the file is placed  in the appropriate location. I am on linux.

@CobaltBlue Do you have the ngspice XSPICE extensions compiled/installed? I am recalling now that the PWL diode model is implemented in XSPICE. Not a problem on Windows since the XSPICE files ship with the program, but on Linux it has to be compiled separately (or something like that where it’s a flag you have to set when compiling).

@CobaltBlue  Starting with ngspice-43, the compile script does this by default (see section 28.0.1.2 of ngspice-43 manual).  But before that version, you need to add the --enable-xspice to the compile command (see section 32.1.2 of ngspice-42 manual).
